# Objects not positioned in order in mobile devices

Tags: html, media-queries

I have developed this page for 2 types of devices. One is for widths below 1000px and one is for widths above 1000px. I'm getting the desired results in devices of width above 1000px. But for devices below 1000px, the top text which reads "welcome to v! Tap on the pig for intro" is only half viewable. Also the bg-img I'm using completely occupying page. If I reduce the width of playpause, the background is also reducing. I want the background color to fill all the page and resize the bg-img to fit in page along with the welcome text. I want the text to be on top of image and centered. I've tried changing several elements in CSS but none helped. Please help!

```js
document.getElementById('myVideo').addEventListener('ended', function() {
  window.location.href = 'http://www.vvv.com/index_home.html';
}, false);

$('.video').parent().click(function() {
  if ($(this).children(".video").get(0).paused) {
    $(this).children(".video").get(0).play();
    $(this).children(".playpause").fadeOut();
    $(this).children(".click").fadeOut();
  } else {
    $(this).children(".video").get(0).pause();
    $(this).children(".playpause").fadeIn();
    $(this).children(".click").fadeIn();
  }
});
```

```css
html {
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

body {
  height: 90%;
  width: auto;
  background-color: white;
}

.wrapper {
  width=100%;
  height=90%;
}

a {
  font-size: 21px;
  color: #FF69B4;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .skip {
    background-color: black;
    position: fixed;
    right: 5;
    padding: 5px;
    bottom: 145px;
  }
  body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 90%;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .video {
    object-fit: contain;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: -9px;
    margin-top: -100px;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100%;
    border: 0px solid black;
  }
  .wrapper {
    display: table-cell;
    width: auto;
    position: absolute;
  }
  .click {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "MS Sans Serif", Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 17px;
    color: #6c03fc;
    font-variant: small caps;
    margin-top: -20px;
  }
  .playpause {
    background-image: url("http://pngimg.com/uploads/man/man_PNG6532.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: #A1A19D;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 20px;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    left: 0%;
    right: 0%;
    top: 0%;
    bottom: 0%;
    margin: auto;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1001px) and (max-width: 2700px) {
  .skip {
    background-color: black;
    position: fixed;
    right: 50px;
    padding: 5px;
    bottom: 20px;
  }
  .click {
    font-family: "MS Sans Serif", Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #6c03fc;
    font-variant: small caps;
  }
  body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .wrapper {
    display: table-cell;
    width: auto;
    position: relative;
  }
  .video {
    background-color: black !important;
    object-fit: contain;
    width: 200vh;
    height: 100vh;
  }
  .playpause {
    background-image: url("http://pngimg.com/uploads/man/man_PNG6532.png");
    margin-top: 80px;
    top: 20;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: #A1A19D;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0%;
    right: 0%;
    top: 0%;
    bottom: 0%;
    margin: auto;
    background-position: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <video class="video" width="100%" height="auto" id="myVideo" autoplay="autoplay">
    <source src="https://download.blender.org/peach/trailer/trailer_400p.ogg" />
  </video><br>
  <div class="skip">
    <a href="/index_home.html">Skip intro</a>
  </div>
  <div class="playpause">
    <b><p class="click">WELCOME TO V! <br> TAP ON THE PIG FOR INTRO</p><br></b>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `margin-top: -20px;`. Remove it and you see the full text.

**Working example:**

```js
document.getElementById('myVideo').addEventListener('ended', function() {
  window.location.href = 'http://www.vvv.com/index_home.html';
}, false);

$('.video').parent().click(function() {
  if ($(this).children(".video").get(0).paused) {
    $(this).children(".video").get(0).play();
    $(this).children(".playpause").fadeOut();
    $(this).children(".click").fadeOut();
  } else {
    $(this).children(".video").get(0).pause();
    $(this).children(".playpause").fadeIn();
    $(this).children(".click").fadeIn();
  }
});
```

```css
html {
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

body {
  height: 90%;
  width: auto;
  background-color: white;
}

.wrapper {
  width=100%;
  height=90%;
}

a {
  font-size: 21px;
  color: #FF69B4;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .skip {
    background-color: black;
    position: fixed;
    right: 5;
    padding: 5px;
    bottom: 145px;
  }
  body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 90%;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .video {
    object-fit: contain;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: -9px;
    margin-top: -100px;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100%;
    border: 0px solid black;
  }
  .wrapper {
    display: table-cell;
    width: auto;
    position: absolute;
  }
  .click {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "MS Sans Serif", Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 17px;
    color: #6c03fc;
    font-variant: small caps;
  }
  .playpause {
    background-image: url("http://pngimg.com/uploads/man/man_PNG6532.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: #A1A19D;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    left: 0%;
    right: 0%;
    top: 0%;
    bottom: 0%;
    margin: auto;
    background-size: auto 90%;
    background-position: bottom;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1001px) and (max-width: 2700px) {
  .skip {
    background-color: black;
    position: fixed;
    right: 50px;
    padding: 5px;
    bottom: 20px;
  }
  .click {
    font-family: "MS Sans Serif", Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #6c03fc;
    font-variant: small caps;
  }
  body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .wrapper {
    display: table-cell;
    width: auto;
    position: relative;
  }
  .video {
    background-color: black !important;
    object-fit: contain;
    width: 200vh;
    height: 100vh;
  }
  .playpause {
    background-image: url("http://pngimg.com/uploads/man/man_PNG6532.png");
    margin-top: 80px;
    top: 20;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: #A1A19D;
    background-size: contain;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0%;
    right: 0%;
    top: 0%;
    bottom: 0%;
    margin: auto;
    background-position: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js">
</script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <video class="video" width="100%" height="auto" id="myVideo" autoplay="autoplay">
    <source src="https://download.blender.org/peach/trailer/trailer_400p.ogg" />
  </video><br>
  <div class="skip">
    <a href="/index_home.html">Skip intro</a>
  </div>
  <div class="playpause">
    <b><p class="click">WELCOME TO V! <br> TAP ON THE PIG FOR INTRO</p><br></b>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oops I forgot it. It did work! thanks. How can I resize the image without reducing the background color?

Comment: What do you mean with "without reducing the background-color"? Both are independent...

Comment: But when I reduce the width hoping it will  reduce the size of the image, both are getting reduced...

Comment: I still don't understand but presume that you mean that the background-image in desktop-mode was too big. Therefor i added `background-size: contain;` in my answer so that the image fits the container...

Comment: I'm trying to resize background-image in mobile-mode....It fits the screen but the welcome text is overlaying the image. I want it to be on top followed by bg-img.

Comment: I added in my answer for the mobile view `background-size: auto 90%;` to `.playpause`...

Comment: Yes please, I've tried margin top but it didn't help

Comment: I'll check it up and let you know in a while... Thank you so much for your time man

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234372/discussion-between-vambay-colony-and-biberman).